# Why I cannot use 'VertexColors' parameter from Threejs?

Tags: three.js

I'm using threejs to provide a 3D animation...

this is my main.js file content:

```
import './style.css'

import {
    AxesHelper,
    BufferGeometry,
    Float32BufferAttribute,
    MathUtils,
    PerspectiveCamera,
    Points,
    PointsMaterial,
    Scene,
    TextureLoader,
    VertexColors,
    WebGLRenderer,
} from "three";

import {OrbitControls} from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';

const count = 100;
const distance = 2;

const textureLoader = new TextureLoader();
const circleTexture = textureLoader.load("ball.png");

const scene = new Scene();

scene.add(new AxesHelper());

const camera = new PerspectiveCamera(75,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,0.01,1000);

camera.position.z = 2;
camera.position.y = 0.5;
camera.position.x = 0.5;

scene.add(camera);

const pts = new Float32Array(count * 3);
const colors = new Float32Array(count * 3);
for (let i = 0; i < pts.length; i++) {
    pts[i] = MathUtils.randFloatSpread(distance * 2);
    colors[i] = Math.random();
}

const geometry = new BufferGeometry();
geometry.setAttribute('position', new Float32BufferAttribute(pts,3));
geometry.setAttribute('colors', new Float32BufferAttribute(colors,3));
const pointMaterial = new PointsMaterial({
    size: 0.1,
    map : circleTexture,
    alphaTest: 0.01,
    transparent: true,
    vertexColors : VertexColors,
});
const points = new Points(geometry, pointMaterial);
scene.add(points);

const renderer = new WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true, //removing all ugly pixels from cube's sides
    alpha : true,
});
renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio,2));
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

function anime() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    controls.update();
    requestAnimationFrame(anime);
}

anime();

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix(); // mettre a jour la camera...
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio,2));
});
```

in PointsMaterial() constructor , I want to assign a value to vertexColor to make a variety of colors for my objects (3D looking points...), but I got the following error on the console :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/three.js?v=19235266' does not provide an export named 'VertexColors' (at main.js?t=1655672405709:13:5)
```

it seems like threejs doesn't contain this property or what ??!!!

Comment: `vertexColors` is bool, thus, either `true` or `false`. https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=material#api/en/materials/Material.vertexColors

Comment: @prisoner849 Yess I already seen that, but why I cannot get VertexColors Imported From THREE ?